# Grid not updating upon change in model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Folks,

I am using ng-grid to display a list of items. 
I want to give my users ability to rearrange the rows in the list. 
i.e move the rows up and down as they please.

Now, 
However when I update the grid data in the backend i.e say change the index of a particular row, that row does not automatically change locations in the front-end.

What am i missing here ?

I have created a plunker to describe the problem
http://plnkr.co/edit/s1hrTSqF2zeZo3Btaln0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid doesn't use the index of the array to order it, so even if you are changing it, because the data is still there nothing happens.

What you could do is define an order field and update the value then changing the values [as shown in this plukr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9EwjAA5KxbyE9rqD0rQK). The order field you can hide it from the grid if required using columnDefs to explicitly defined which column should be shown.

Regards